# EDB char array problem. New input word overlaps the previous words saved

Tags: arduino-uno, datalogging

I have been searching everywhere now and nothing seems to work out for me. When I try to input a new word, it overlaps the previously entered words.
Here is my struct definition:

```
struct LogEvent{
  char fullname[30];  
} logEvent;
```

Here is how I assign a value to fullname:

```
strcpy(logEvent.fullname, testName);
```

Here is how I print the output:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= db.count(); i++)
{
  EDB_Status result = db.readRec(i, EDB_REC logEvent);
  if(result == EDB_OK)
  {
     Serial.print(logEvent.fullname);
     Serial.print(" ");
  }
}
```

Here is the sample output:

```
Input 1 - Lebron James  
Output 1- Lebron James

Input 2 - Kobe Bryant
Output 2 - Kobe Bryant Kobe Bryant  (The output should be - Lebron James Kobe Bryant)

Input 3 - LeGoat 
Output 3 - LeGoat LeGoat LeGoat (The output should be - Lebron James Kobe Bryant LeGoat)
```

**How to fix this?**

EDIT. Here is my code:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include <EDB.h>

// Use the external SPI SD card as storage
#include <SPI.h>  
#include <SD.h>

int recnumber = 1;  
//Arbitrary definition
struct LogEvent {
    int id;
    int temperature;
    char fullname[30];
}
logEvent;  


inline void writer (unsigned long address, const byte* data, unsigned int  recsize) {
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    dbFile.seek(address);
    dbFile.write(data,recsize);
    dbFile.flush();
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);
}

inline void reader (unsigned long address, byte* data, unsigned int recsize) {
   digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
   dbFile.seek(address);
   dbFile.read(data,recsize);
   digitalWrite(13, LOW);
}  
  EDB db(&writer, &reader);

// Run the demo
void setup()
{
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);

    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println(" Extended Database Library + External SD CARD storage demo");
    Serial.println();

    randomSeed(analogRead(0));

    if (!SD.begin(SD_PIN)) {
        Serial.println("No SD-card.");
        return;
    }

    // Check dir for db files
    if (!SD.exists("/db")) {
        Serial.println("Dir for Db files does not exist, creating...");
        SD.mkdir("/db");
    }

    if (SD.exists(db_name)) {

        dbFile = SD.open(db_name, FILE_WRITE);

      // Sometimes it wont open at first attempt, espessialy after cold start
      // Let's try one more time
        if (!dbFile) {
            dbFile = SD.open(db_name, FILE_WRITE);
        }

        if (dbFile) {
            Serial.print("Openning current table... ");
            EDB_Status result = db.open(0);
            if (result == EDB_OK) {
                Serial.println("DONE");
            } else {
                Serial.println("ERROR");
                Serial.println("Did not find database in the file " + String(db_name));
                Serial.print("Creating new table... ");
                db.create(0, TABLE_SIZE, (unsigned int)sizeof(logEvent));
                Serial.println("DONE");
                return;
            }
        } else {
            Serial.println("Could not open file " + String(db_name));
            return;
        }
    } else {
        Serial.print("Creating table... ");
        // create table at with starting address 0
        dbFile = SD.open(db_name, FILE_WRITE);
        db.create(0, TABLE_SIZE, (unsigned int)sizeof(logEvent));
        Serial.println("DONE");
    }
    deleteAll();
    recordLimit();
    countRecords();  
}
char testName[30];   

void loop()
{
  if(Serial.available())
  {
    Serial.println("Waiting for name...");
    index = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(testName); ++i)
    {
      testName[i] = (char)0;
    }
    while(Serial.available())
    {
      char character = Serial.read();
      testName[index] = character;
      index++;
    }
    createRecords(testName);
    selectAll();
    delay(1000);
  } 
  delay(1000);
 }  

void createRecords(char *testName)
{
  Serial.print("Creating Record... ");
  logEvent.id = recnumber;
  logEvent.temperature = random(1, 125);
  strcpy(logEvent.fullname, testName);
  recnumber++;
  EDB_Status result = db.appendRec(EDB_REC logEvent);
}

void selectAll()
{
   for (int recno = 1; recno <= db.count(); recno++)
   {
      EDB_Status result = db.readRec(recno, EDB_REC logEvent);
      if (result == EDB_OK)
      {
        Serial.print("Recno: ");
        Serial.print(recno);
        Serial.print(" ID: ");
        Serial.print(logEvent.id);
        Serial.print(" Temp: ");
        Serial.print(logEvent.temperature);
        Serial.print(" Fullname: ");
        Serial.print(logEvent.fullname);
        Serial.print(" Length: ");
        Serial.println(strlen(logEvent.fullname));
      }
    }
 }
```

Here is the output:

```
Extended Database Library + External SD CARD storage demo

Openning current table... DONE
Truncating table... DONE
Record Limit: 2045
Record Count: 0
Record Count: 0
Waiting for name...
Name received: Kobe Bryant
LogEvent Fullname: 
The sentence entered is 11 characters long
Creating Record... Done Creating Record...
Recno: 1 ID: 1 Temp: 64 Fullname: Kobe Bryant Length: 11
Waiting for name...
Name received: Lebron James
LogEvent Fullname: Kobe Bryant
The sentence entered is 12 characters long
Recno: 1 ID: 1 Temp: 64 Fullname: Kobe Bryant Length: 11
Creating Record... Done Creating Record...
Recno: 1 ID: 1 Temp: 64 Fullname: Lebron James Length: 12
Recno: 2 ID: 2 Temp: 78 Fullname: Lebron James Length: 12
Waiting for name...
Name received: Michael Jordan
LogEvent Fullname: Lebron James
The sentence entered is 14 characters long
Recno: 1 ID: 1 Temp: 64 Fullname: Lebron James Length: 12
Recno: 2 ID: 2 Temp: 78 Fullname: Lebron James Length: 12
Creating Record... Done Creating Record...
Recno: 1 ID: 1 Temp: 64 Fullname: Michael Jordan Length: 14
Recno: 2 ID: 2 Temp: 78 Fullname: Michael Jordan Length: 14
Recno: 3 ID: 3 Temp: 29 Fullname: Michael Jordan Length: 14
```

Update: I tried to use `memset` but the result is still the same as above.

Comment: The sample output doesn't correspond with the your code. Publish a complete, mininal code that show the result you posted.

Comment: @LookAlterno Sure

Comment: `memset` fill a block of memory with a given value. See it http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/

Comment: Okay, I'll try to work on that.

Comment: Your code looks clean and well structured, and you have a good debugging approach, but code and output doesn't match (and `setup` is missing). Your question is valuable; please edit it so code and output match. And complete, so others can test it easily.

Comment: Okay. Working on it.

Comment: Can you upload the arrangement you made here I have the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. The problem is with the SD card library of Arduino. I downloaded this library [sdFat library](https://github.com/greiman/SdFat/tree/master/examples), included it in the sketch `#include "SdFat.h"`, and defined `SdFat SD`. I also removed the `#include <SD.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried to extend one of the examples (with internal EEPROM), and it's working as expected:

```cpp
/*
 EDB_Simple.pde
 Extended Database Library + Internal Arduino EEPROM Demo Sketch 

 The Extended Database library project page is here:
 http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Code/ExtendedDatabaseLibrary

 */
#include "Arduino.h"
#include <EDB.h>

// Use the Internal Arduino EEPROM as storage
#include <EEPROM.h>

// Uncomment the line appropriate for your platform
#define TABLE_SIZE 512 // Arduino 168 or greater

// The number of demo records that should be created.  This should be less 
// than (TABLE_SIZE - sizeof(EDB_Header)) / sizeof(LogEvent).  If it is higher, 
// operations will return EDB_OUT_OF_RANGE for all records outside the usable range.
#define RECORDS_TO_CREATE 10

// Arbitrary record definition for this table.  
// This should be modified to reflect your record needs.
struct LogEvent {
  int id;
  int temperature;
  char test[20] = {};
} 
logEvent;


// The read and write handlers for using the EEPROM Library
void writer(unsigned long address, byte data)
{
  EEPROM.write(address, data);
}

byte reader(unsigned long address)
{
  return EEPROM.read(address);
}

// Create an EDB object with the appropriate write and read handlers
EDB db(&writer, &reader);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Extended Database Library + Arduino Internal EEPROM Demo");
  Serial.println();

  db.create(0, TABLE_SIZE, sizeof(logEvent));

  Serial.print("Record Count: "); Serial.println(db.count());

  Serial.println("Creating Records...");
  int recno;
  for (recno = 1; recno <= RECORDS_TO_CREATE; recno++)
  {
    logEvent.id = recno; 
    logEvent.temperature = recno * 2;
    strcpy(logEvent.test, (String{recno*3} + " whatever " + recno).c_str());
    db.appendRec(EDB_REC logEvent);
  }

  Serial.print("Record Count: "); Serial.println(db.count());
  // Thanks to katts0...@gmail.com for the next line
  for (recno = 1; recno <= RECORDS_TO_CREATE; recno++)
  {
    db.readRec(recno, EDB_REC logEvent);
    Serial.print("ID: "); Serial.print(logEvent.id);
    Serial.print(" Temp: "); Serial.print(logEvent.temperature);
    Serial.print(" Data: "); Serial.println(logEvent.test);
  }
}

void loop()
{
}
```

The output:

```
Extended Database Library + Arduino Internal EEPROM Demo

Record Count: 0
Creating Records...
Record Count: 10
ID: 1 Temp: 2 Data: 3 whatever 1
ID: 2 Temp: 4 Data: 6 whatever 2
ID: 3 Temp: 6 Data: 9 whatever 3
ID: 4 Temp: 8 Data: 12 whatever 4
ID: 5 Temp: 10 Data: 15 whatever 5
ID: 6 Temp: 12 Data: 18 whatever 6
ID: 7 Temp: 14 Data: 21 whatever 7
ID: 8 Temp: 16 Data: 24 whatever 8
ID: 9 Temp: 18 Data: 27 whatever 9
ID: 10 Temp: 20 Data: 30 whatever 10
```

Comment: I'll try to look into this.

Comment: I tried this and it is working as you said. Maybe my problem is with the SD Card library `SD.h`

Comment: @Xirb or reader/writer is not working as expecter. I've used different signatures - it's called for each byte